# Does Binary Search guarantees that one of the THREE variables used in the algorithm will hold the right position of the key?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, binary-search

The title may not clear what I want to ask because it is not complete (SO restricted me to 150 words for the title).

My question is, Does Binary Search guarantees that one of the THREE variables used in the algorithm will hold the right position of the key, EVEN IF IT WAS NOT FOUND IN THE GIVEN SORTED SEQUENCE?

I have an example to clarify the question.

Consider a sorted array A with length 5;

```
int a[] = {2, 8, 9, 11, 14};
```

Clearly, the array doesn't contain 7. By looking at the sequence, we can say that the element 7 would have been given the index 1 if in the array.

Performing a binary search in the above sequence with key 7, will return -1 (that depends on the implementation, of course). But, does any of the three variables, say p (that if becomes greater than r, breaks the loop), q (stores the (p + r) / 2) and r (that if becomes less than p, breaks the loop) will hold the correct position (which is 1) for the value 7 in the above sequence, when the loop breaks?

Or, can some mathematical computation help us find the right position of 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see, binary search returns with -1 when the high and low index of array be the same. These indexes will be the same and on the position that it was assumed that the number is there. (Here index 1)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes !** check for `a[low]` and `a[high]` otherwise perform Binary Search. `mid` variable will store the exact location where the element should get placed before or after `a[mid]`

`low = 0` and `high = arrar_length - 1`
check this code for reference. http://ideone.com/OYv3ih